Theorem 5.6, chapter IV in Kunens Set Theory
Boldface-letters (i.e. $\mathbf{A}$,$\mathbf{V}$,etc.) indicate a class.
The following is an excerpt from Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs" (theorem 5.6, $\S5$ of chapter IV).

Let $\mathbf{R}$ be a relation which is well-founded and set-like on $\mathbf{A}$, and $\mathbf{F}:\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{V}$. Let $\mathbf{G}:\mathbf{A} \to \mathbf{V}$ be defined as in III 5.6, so that $$\forall x \in \mathbf{A}[\mathbf{G}(x) = \mathbf{F}(x,\mathbf{G}\upharpoonright \text{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R}))].$$ Let $\mathbf{M}$ be a transitive model of $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$ and assume that

$\mathbf{F}$ is absolute for $\mathbf{M}$.
$\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ are absolute for $\mathbf{M}$, $(\text{$\mathbf{R}$ is set-like on $\mathbf{A}$})^{\mathbf{M}}$ and $$\forall x \in \mathbf{M}(\mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R}) \subset \mathbf{M}).$$ Then $\mathbf{G}$ is absolute for $\mathbf{M}$.


In Kunen, a proof follows for the above statement:

Note first that $(\text{$\mathbf{R}$ is well-founded on $\mathbf{A}$})^{\mathbf{M}}$ since $\mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{M}} = \mathbf{R} \cap(\mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M})$ is well-founded on $\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}} = \mathbf{A} \cap \mathbf{M}$, so any non-empty subset of $\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}}$ in $\mathbf{M}$ has an $\mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{M}}$-minimal element. Thus, we may apply transfinite recursion (my comment: see theorem 5.6 in III of chapter IV) within $\mathbf{M}$ to define $\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}}:\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}} \to \mathbf{M}$ such that $$\forall x \in \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}}[\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}} = \mathbf{F}^{\mathbf{M}}(x,\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}} \upharpoonright \mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}},x,\mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{M}}))].$$ But then $\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}} = \mathbf{G} \upharpoonright \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}}$ by transfinite induction; that is, an $\mathbf{R}$-minimal element of $\{x \in \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}}: \mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}}(x) \neq \mathbf{G}(x)\}$ would, by our assumed absoluteness statements (my italic), lead to a contradiction. $\blacksquare$

It is basically the last paragraph above, and in particular the statement in italic, of that paragraph, I am having trouble understanding. I should say that I also don't see where we use the following assumptions:

Absoluteness of $\mathbf{F}$.
$\forall x \in \mathbf{M}(\mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R}) \subset \mathbf{M})$.

I'd be grateful for being enlightened as to the details of especially the last part of this proof.
Comment: So, we know that $\mathbf{F}^{\mathbf{M}}(x,y) = \mathbf{F}(x,y)$. Furthermore, we know that $\mathbf{A}$  is absolute for $\mathbf{M} \iff \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}} = \mathbf{A} \cap \mathbf{M}$, and we know that $\mathbf{R}$ is absolute for $\mathbf{M} \iff \mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{M}} = \mathbf{R} \cap \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M}$. We also know that $\forall x \in \mathbf{M}(\mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R}) \subset \mathbf{M})$. Is it the case that if $\exists x \in \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}} \subset \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}}(x) \neq \mathbf{G}(x))$, this would contradict the absoluteness of $\mathbf{F}$?
I don't see exactly how to interpret $\mathrm{pred}^{\mathbf{M}}$; that is, how to relativize $\mathrm{pred}$ to $\mathbf{M}$. Perhaps this is causing some of the confusion. Is $\mathrm{pred}^{\mathbf{M}}(\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}},x,\mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{M}}) = \{y \in \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}} : y\mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{M}}x\}$?
Comment 2: One should perhaps note that the condition $$\forall x \in \mathbf{M}(\mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R}) \subset \mathbf{M})$$ ensures that $\mathbf{M}$ is downwards closed with respect to $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{R}$. I believe this might be useful. I am somewhat unsure why $\mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R})$ makes sense when $x \in \mathbf{M}$, since we don't know that $x \in \mathbf{A}$. I think I have only seen $\mathrm{pred}$ defined in a context where $x \in \mathbf{A}$ if we have $\mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R})$ (atleast when $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{R}$ are sets).

Assume that $\{x \in \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}} : \mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}}(x) \neq \mathbf{G}(x)\}$ has an $\mathbf{R}$-minimal element $y$.
Since on $x \in \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}}$ we have $\mathrm{pred}^{\mathbf{M}}(\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}},x,\mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{M}}) = \mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R})$ (unless I am mistaken), it follows that  since $\mathbf{F}$ is absolute on $\mathbf{M}$, we see that $\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}}\upharpoonright \mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R}) \neq \mathbf{G} \upharpoonright \mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R})$. But by definition , then there $\exists z\mathbf{R}y$ such that $\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}}(z) \neq \mathbf{G}(z)$, contradicting the $\mathbf{R}$-minimality of $y$.
Clarification. The reason we have $\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}}\upharpoonright \mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R}) \neq \mathbf{G} \upharpoonright \mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R})$ is that $$\forall x \in \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}}[\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}}(x) = \mathbf{F}^{\mathbf{M}}(x,\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}} \upharpoonright \mathrm{pred}^{\mathbf{M}}(\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}},x,\mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{M}}))]$$ simplifies to $$\forall x \in \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}}[\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}}(x) = \mathbf{F}(x,\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}} \upharpoonright \mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R}))].$$ So $\mathbf{G}^{\mathbf{M}}\upharpoonright \mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R}) \neq \mathbf{G} \upharpoonright \mathrm{pred}(\mathbf{A},x,\mathbf{R})$, otherwise this would contradict the existence of $y$.
